# Azure: enable partitioning for existed service bus queue

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

my department has set up a service bus queue before, but the partitioning is not enabled. Are there any ways to enable it? or do I have to delete it and create a new one with the same name to enable the partitioning? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only enable partitioning at the time of creation of a queue. So your only option would be to delete the existing queue and recreate it with partitioning enabled.

Comment: Hi, can I simply delete the old queue and build a new one with the same name, or there are extra steps I should know?

Comment: No, nothing special. Just delete the old queue and create a new one with partitioning enabled.